# Build Security Token Service (STS) application in ASP.NET for SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, wif, claims-authentication

I have created a new ASP.NET web site using VS 2017 and changed the Authentication mechanism to use "Individual User Accounts". This adds the Claims Principal or WIF class support.I can click on register / log in, and set up user emails and then check for the claims for that user. I will also be using Server Session Authentication Management (SAM) to save claims on the server and do some claims transformation as well.

After Login, this site calls a winform application, and after some activity I return back to the above website.

I want to know how can I use SSO logic here and check if I am already Authenticated and access my claims saved at the server side / website and authenticate the user based on the saved claims.

Is there some project or code example anyone can give which i can use as a start to develop such a STS service (in VS 2017) with SSO and access my claims on website after coming from another domain?

The identity and access tools used to work only with VS 2012, so any way to replicate the above scenario and check for my saved claims after I hit my website from the winform application.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation) of using WS-Fed with Azure AD.

This is easily adaptable to ADFS.

Your other choice is to use [ADAL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop/).

Comment: The client is not using AD currently, but uses SQL server to maintain login credentials. Keeping that in mind I created a membership type claims example in asp.net with out of box login page and registration.
After login I generate the user claims and have it save it on server with Session Authentication Management.
Now after redirect from windows form app to the website, I want to use these claims or an STS which auto authenticates me, based on expiration time.